# Does there exist an integer $x$ satisfying the following congruence:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Does there exist an integer $x$ satisfying the following congruence:

$10x=1\mod 21$

$5x=1\mod 6$

$4x=1\mod 7$

**My try**:

Using Chinese Remainder Theorem:

$n=n_1*n_2*n_3=21*6*7=882$ .
Then consider  $n_1^{'}=42,n_2^{'}=147,n_3^{'}=126$.

Consider $n_1^{'}x \equiv 1\mod n_1$,$n_2^{'}x \equiv 1\mod n_2$,$n_3^{'}x \equiv 1\mod n_3$
.

Substituting we get $42x\equiv 1\mod(21)$,$147x\equiv 1\mod(6)$,$126x\equiv 1\mod(7)$

But  $42x\equiv 1\mod(21)$, is never true as $21*2=42$

Thus no such solution exists. Is this true?

Comment: If there is one, it will be $0 \le x < 2 \times 3 \times 7$

Comment: I thought CRT requires the modulo numbers be pairwise relatively prime?  21, 6, 7 don't meet that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$10x \equiv 1 \pmod{21} \implies x \equiv 19 \pmod{21}$

$5x \equiv 1 \pmod{6} \implies x \equiv 5 \pmod{6}$

$4x \equiv 1 \pmod{7} \implies x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$

So, $x=21t+19$ for some $t \in \mathbb{N}$. Putting this into the second equation gives $21t+19 \equiv 5 \pmod{6} \implies 21t \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$.

If, $t$ is even then $6 \mid 21t$. If $t$ is odd, then $21t$ is an odd number modulo $6$. So, this isn't possible. Hence, there exists no such $x$.

Comment: Note $x \equiv 19 \pmod{21}$ implies $x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$ Since this contradicts $x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$, there can be no solution.

Comment: @StevenGregori Right you are.

Comment: thank you @StevenGregory;@Sayantan

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

The [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) needs the coefficients of  $x$ to be same

As $4\cdot2\equiv1\pmod7,$

$$4x\equiv1\pmod7\iff x\equiv2$$ etc.

Comment: how to make the co-efficients same?

Comment: @learnmore, As I've started making the coefficient $=1$